# How to get all the files created by an user on Sharepoint using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, rest, onedrive-for-business

I am trying to get all the files created by a specific user using userid.

The below REST url is what I am trying:

```
https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/_api/files?$select=Title,CreatedBy&$expand=CreatedBy&$filter=CreatedBy/Id eq '10'
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-1, System.NotSupportedException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Specified method is not supported."
        }
    }

}
```

When I use only `$select` and `$filter` I get the expected result.

But when I use `$expand` I am getting the above error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the expected output using the below url.

```
https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Documents?$select=CreatedById&$filter=CreatedById eq 12
```

Answer (score 0):

The $expand columns must also be included in $select

Marc has a sample: http://sympmarc.com/2014/01/21/getting-user-information-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/

Comment: I tried this, _api/files?$select=Title,CreatedBy/Id&$expand=CreatedBy/Id&$filter=CreatedBy/Id eq '12' but still i am getting the same error

Comment: Try substituting CreatedBy with Author as this is the underlying field name.

Comment: Which is exactly what Marc's sample shows...

Comment: The URLs in Marc's sample are based on User Information List( /_api/web/lists) but here I am working on _api/files